# Best way to create HTML attribute from CSS class with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with a server-side framework that will not allow the creation of some new HTML 5 attributes. Though eventually it will be upgraded to allow, I need a temporary fix to insert attributes such as *placeholder*.

The jsFiddle below creates the attribute with js/jQuery from a pseudo-attribute class.

- Are there any downsides to this method (other than its hackishness)
- Is there a better way?

http://jsfiddle.net/luke_charde/HCMUJ/

Comment: why did you use the class attribute? you could set a new attribute like <input type="text" ux-placeholder="dd/mm/yy' />

Comment: I am not able to put any attributes other than the standard attributes allowed in XHTML.

Comment: The lovely and talented Stripes framework has two .tld sets to choose from: one is strict about attributes, and one isn't. Thus you can code pages mostly with the strict tags, but then use the relaxed one when you really, really want that "data-shoe-size" attribute.

Comment: Maybe you can use the 'title' attribute, if that doesn't bother you

Comment: @Pointy Stripes looks interesting... currently fighting with legacy Java Server Faces 1.2  @yoav thanks... possible... but I have to give accessibility signoff, so class may be less problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could use [the jQuery "metadata" plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata), which would allow you to migrate your class-based attribute scheme to something like "data-foo" (if you wanted to) later without having to change the JS code.

However I don't see anything particularly wrong with what you've done, though because I'm lazy I'd probably have picked a shorter marker string :-)

Comment: Thanks, Pointy. Good point.  "ux-" is the naming prefix of the project's css.

Comment: Ah ok - I read the code quickly. I've got a whole bunch of code that uses a similar deal, via my own (really simple) jQuery plugin that unpacks "key:value" pairs from the class.